# Ctrl+C different from Range.Copy()

Tags: c#, openxml, import-from-excel

I have an Excel sheet to programmatically check if some cells have hidden data. 
The situation is when I do a Ctrl+C on a cell and Crl+V in Notepad++ it shows more data from the one shown in Excel.

I'm using Open XML SDK 2.5 to access the sheet in C#.

The property Range.Text returns the shown text, not hidden data. The method Range.Copy also returns the shown text. I make a range.copy and get from Clipboard and the hidden data doesn't come.

Do you have an idea in how to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the issue? You do or do not want hidden data to come?

Comment: I need the hidden data to come, I need to verify that it exists when it really exist.

Comment: By hidden data, do you mean that the value is formatted and you can't see all the decimals? You need to use `Range.Value` or `Range.Value2` to get the actual value. `Range.Text` will only give you what's displayed.

Comment: I mean by hidden data like this example: Cell shows "http://url1" and when you use Crtl+C and Ctrl+V in notepad you get "http://url1 http://url2 http://url3". `Range.Value` and `Range.Value2` shows "http://url1" both.